# Animated gif image in tree node

Tags: java, swing, jtree, animated-gif, treenode

I am trying to add an animated gif image to a tree Node but apparently JTree is the only component that cannot render the gif animation. Can you please advise me how to fix this?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImageIcon leafIcon = new ImageIcon(any_gif_animated_image);

        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
        renderer.setClosedIcon(leafIcon);
        renderer.setOpenIcon(leafIcon);
        renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);

        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(leafIcon);
        label.setText("loading");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(900, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Animated Icon Tree Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AnimatedIconTreeExample.htm)
2. [Animated Gif Icon (any_gif_animated_image)](http://www.gifanimations.com/GA/animation/MenuSelection/1/28)
3. produce crazy animation in the JTree node

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the main idea is to use an ImageObserver which will take the next frame of a gif image and show it, right?

Comment: Also, Do I have to create an ImageIcon for each Node because if I reuse the same icon for all nodes, Only the first node is having an animated icon, the rest are static?

Comment: Update: I used 'tree.repaint()' instead and it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: notice most of animated Gif has awfull frequency as Object in Renderer

Comment: And what do you mean by that?

Comment: I tried a few animated gifs, some of them (refresh frequency) shaking on the screen or crazy rotating ....